# The constructor ClientArguments(String[], SparkConf) is undefined

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying spark-submit through Java code. I am referring the following example.

https://github.com/mahmoudparsian/data-algorithms-book/blob/master/misc/how-to-submit-spark-job-to-yarn-from-java-code.md

But I am getting

```
The constructor ClientArguments(String[], SparkConf) is undefined
```

My version of spark-yarn is `spark-yarn_2.11-2.0.0`.

I saw the topic :
 [spark-submit through java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514786/spark-submit-through-java-code)

but it does not work for me.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor arguments have changed between 1.x and 2.0. In 1.x it looked like:

`ClientArguments(args: Array[String], sparkConf: SparkConf)`

In 2.0 its:

`ClientArguments(args: Array[String])`

See: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ClientArguments.scala